# How to add line numbers to a file in Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I have a file `names.txt` with this data:

```
NAME;AGE;
alberto;22
andrea;51
ana;16
```

and I want to add a new column `N` with the line number of the row:

```
N;NAME;AGE;
1;alberto;22
2;andrea;51
3;ana;16
```

I've been looking and what I found was something related with `Add sequence`. I tried but I don't know how.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add Sequence` step will get the job done, but you don't even need that. Both the `CSV file input` and `Text file input` steps can add a row number to the input rows. For the 'CSV file input' step it's called 'The row number field name (optional)'.

For `Text file input`, check the 'Rownum in output?' box on the Content tab and fill in the 'Rownum fieldname' text box.

I'm really baffled why you couldn't figure out the `Add sequence` step. It should work with no changes at all. Just drop it in and connect the output of the csv file to it and the sequence should appear as a field name called 'valuename'. I would change that personally, but still, it should work.

Comment: Oh, thank you. It seems a stupid question but I always think in the most difficult way to do. Thank you very very much. Greetings from Spain.